# Handle exception in rxjs ajax.map call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs, redux-observable

I've created an epic based off the "[fetch user demo](https://jsbin.com/jopuza/10/edit?html,css,js,output)" on the [redux-observable website](https://redux-observable.js.org/).

I'm just wondering how I can add error handling to the ajax request. My attempt:

```
const fetchCategoriesEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_CATEGORIES)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      ajax.getJSON(`http://localhost:4000/categories`)
        .map(
          response => fetchCategoriesFulfilled(response),
          error => console.log(error)
        )
    )
```

I'm testing while the API i'm calling is down to test error handling. Still getting this in the console and the app crashes:

> ExceptionsManager.js:71 Unhandled JS Exception: ajax error 0

If [this is the official docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/getjson.md) then do I get rid of map and do subscribe instead?

I changed it to this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'

const fetchCategoriesEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_CATEGORIES)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      ajax.getJSON(`http://localhost:4000/categories`)
        .map(
          response => fetchCategoriesFulfilled(response)
        ).catch( err => console.log(err))
    )
```

But got:

> You provided undefined where a stream was expected. You can provide an
>   obserable, promise, array or iterable

changed to (as per Jay Phelps's answer [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2059)):

```
const fetchCategoriesEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_CATEGORIES)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      ajax.getJSON(`http://localhost:4000/categories`)
        .map(response => fetchCategoriesFulfilled(response))
        .catch( err => Observable.of(err.xhr.response))
    )
```

got:

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM is for RxJS v4, not v5. The docs for v5 are here: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/ and the source code here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs.

This is definitely confusing, but it's the the unfortunate reality for complex reasons.

---

> You provided undefined where a stream was expected. You can provide an obserable, promise, array or iterable

The reason you're getting this error is indeed, you are not return a stream from your `catch` operator usage as is needed.

The redux-observable docs have a recipe for error handling here: https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/ErrorHandling.html

So it'd look something like this:

```
const fetchCategoriesEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_CATEGORIES)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      ajax.getJSON(`http://localhost:4000/categories`)
        .map(
          response => fetchCategoriesFulfilled(response)
        )
        .catch(error => Observable.of({
          type: FETCH_CATEGORIES_REJECTED,
          error
        }))
    )
```

If you don't actually want to *catch* errors and return another Observable (like an Observable of a single error action) then you can use `.do()` to just log the error:

```
const fetchCategoriesEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_CATEGORIES)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      ajax.getJSON(`http://localhost:4000/categories`)
        .map(
          response => fetchCategoriesFulfilled(response)
        )
        .do({
          error: err => console.log(err)
        })
    )
```

However, if you do not catch the error, it will propagate up the source chain, terminating this Epic and then continuing to propagate terminating your root Epic, making your app probably unusable.

Although I don't recommend this, if you truly want to catch the error but simply swallow it without dispatching and error action, you can do this:

```
const fetchCategoriesEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_CATEGORIES)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      ajax.getJSON(`http://localhost:4000/categories`)
        .map(
          response => fetchCategoriesFulfilled(response)
        )
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
          return Observable.empty();
        })
    )
```

Again, I would highly discourage this--if there's an error you care enough about to catch it, you probably should be handling it in some way such as displaying the error to the user by dispatching an error action and handling that.

---

Edit: based on your new additions

```
.catch( err => Observable.of(err.xhr.response))
```

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Indeed, your epic is now emiting the XHR response on error, not a redux action. Your epic can only emit actions.

Comment: I might be blind, but all I see at http://reactivex.io/rxjs/ is: observable/dom
CAjaxError
CAjaxResponse
CAjaxTimeoutError
IAjaxRequest. Where are the docs describing how to actually use it?